# How i make like this figure?

Tags: exercises

Bonjour,
Comment produire un document avec des exercices dont les corrigés apparaissent à la fin du document et quels soient clickable avec latex.
J'aimerais avoir quelque chose comme ça:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.se! What you try so far? BTW, this is English speaking site :-)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please translate your question into English and add a minimal example of what you tried so far.

Comment: @Sebastiano One of the best duplicate vote I have ever seen!

Comment: @JouleV I'm not used to compliments :-) ahahahah. With my sincerity that I always carry in my heart I remembered that image and zac :-) I found it.

Comment: @Sebastiano It would take me years to find that question

Comment: Bonjour, Unfortunately your question was misunderstood. on thus forum we expect you to supply in English your own attempt (possibly with failings) the answer below will only go part way to your solution as we cannot see what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the option to click on 'solution' to take the user to the answer to the problem you can use

`\label{answer:question:1}`

at the start of the answer and use

`Solution \ref{answer:question:1}`

where you want the user to be able to click.

I hope that helps.